# How to match balanced non empty brackets?

Tags: regex, string, pcre

Using a regular expression, given the following text how can I match the contents between the balanced square brackets but only if not empty?

```
{
    "key1": [
        {
            "key2": "",
            "key3": "",
            "key4": "",
            "key5": []
        }
    ],
    "key6": [
        {
            "key7": "",
            "key8": "",
            "key9": [
                {
                    "key10": "",
                    "key11": "",
                    "key12": "",
                    "key13": []
                }
            ],
            "key14": ""
        }
    ],
    "key15": [],
    "key16": []
}
```

`/\[([\s\S]+)\]/g`: This is my attempt, the idea is that I match the first and last bracket, but this does not work as we don't want to match brackets that are empty i.e. `[]`. It's also not balanced so it's incorrectly matching the open square bracket of `key1` and the closing square bracket of `key16`.

Instead is should be matching the opening and closing bracket of `key1` (i.e. balanced). As we don't want to match empty `[]` we have to be balanced otherwise we will be matching the wrong opening and closing brackets.

The actual problem I'm trying to solve is removing the `[` `]` if not empty. This regex will than be ran recursively in code so that it keeps removing the brackets until it can't find any more matches. I did want to apply this recursively in RegEx but could not work it out.

The resulting text should look like this:

```
{
    "key1": {
        "key2": "",
        "key3": "",
        "key4": "",
        "key5": []
    },
    "key6": {
        "key7": "",
        "key8": "",
        "key9": {
            "key10": "",
            "key11": "",
            "key12": "",
            "key13": []
        },
        "key14": ""
    },
    "key15": [],
    "key16": []
}
```

You can see and play with my regex here:
https://regex101.com/r/bE0jM5/5

Thanks in advance

Comment: Any reason why this has been down voted?

Answer (score 2):

This little monster

```
/\[((\[\s*\]|[^\[\]])+)\]/
```

seems to do the trick:

```js
text = document.querySelector('pre').textContent;

while(1) {
  
  var r = text.replace(/\[((\[\]|[^\[\]])+)\]/g, "$1");
  if(r === text) break;
  text = r;
}

document.querySelector('pre').textContent = text;
```

```html
<pre>
{
    "key1": [
        {
            "key2": "",
            "key3": "",
            "key4": "",
            "key5": []
        }
    ],
    "key6": [
        {
            "key7": "",
            "key8": "",
            "key9": [
                {
                    "key10": "",
                    "key11": "",
                    "key12": "",
                    "key13": []
                }
            ],
            "key14": ""
        }
    ],
    "key15": [],
    "key16": []
}
</pre>
```

If you input is actually JSON, it's much better to parse it and manipulate as an object instead of unreadable and fragile regexes:

```js
text = document.querySelector('pre').textContent;

removeArrays = function(obj) {
  
  if(Array.isArray(obj) && obj.length === 1)
    return removeArrays(obj[0]);
  
  if(typeof obj === "object")
    for(var k in obj)
      obj[k] = removeArrays(obj[k]);
  
  return obj;
}

s = removeArrays(JSON.parse(text));

document.querySelector('pre').textContent = JSON.stringify(s,0,3);
```

```html
<pre>
{
    "key1": [
        {
            "key2": "",
            "key3": "",
            "key4": "",
            "key5": []
        }
    ],
    "key6": [
        {
            "key7": "",
            "key8": "",
            "key9": [
                {
                    "key10": "",
                    "key11": "",
                    "key12": "",
                    "key13": []
                }
            ],
            "key14": ""
        }
    ],
    "key15": [],
    "key16": []
}
</pre>
```

Comment: Almost there...I should have pointed out that the empty arrays might have spaces or newline characters which should be preserved and also not matched, so when I meant ignore empty arrays I also mean `[    ]`. Currently if I add a space or newline in the middle of say the array of key5 that array is incorrectly matched, as it's still empty.

Comment: @Camsoft: re edited... but that's why you should try to use json instead or re's.

Comment: Also you're correct it's JSON but it's being generated by iOS frameworks. It's already been through one pass so is already modified, I'm just trying to remove the remaining braces to make it valid once again.

The actual reason for all the regex is because I need to preserve the order of the objects, but in iOS I have to use arrays of objects to preserve the ordering so I'm having to removing all the arrays in post processing.

The JSON is not actually going to be read by anyone other than a human for debugging object graphs so the JSON format is just to make it pretty formatted.

Comment: Looks like it's still matching the empty array: https://regex101.com/r/bE0jM5/6 -  I've recursed it once, and now key5's empty array has been removed.

Comment: @Camsoft: you can make one more pass before the main loop to replace `\[\s+\]` to `[]`. But this a never-ending battle... what if some of strings happens to contain `[`?

Comment: Agreed, though I'm not looking at tidying up the empty arrays, just that they are not matched by this regex.

Comment: Think I've done it: https://regex101.com/r/bE0jM5/7 - Just needed a lookahead to ignore empty arrays.